# Why I get Forbidden error

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, bitnami

I have created a custom bitnami app at:

```
/opt/redmine-2.6.0-3/apps/widgets
```

but, when I try to access the app from web browser:

```
http://192.168.10.18:8080/widgets/
```

I get error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /widgets/ on this server.
```

`httpd-app.conf` is

```
<Directory /opt/redmine-2.6.0-3/apps/widgets/htdocs>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All

   Allow from all
   Require all granted

</Directory>
```

`httpd-prefix.conf` is:

```
Alias /widgets/ "/opt/redmine-2.6.0-3/apps/widgets/htdocs/"
Alias /widgets "/opt/redmine-2.6.0-3/apps/widgets/htdocs"

Include "/opt/redmine-2.6.0-3/apps/widgets/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

Any one can help?

**Edit**

I've checked the widgets folder permission settings:

```
$ ls -l directory
drwxr-xr-x 6 root daemon 4096 Jan  5 11:23 redmine
drwxr-xr-x 6 root daemon 4096 Mar 11 17:20 widgets

/apps/widgets$ ls -l 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 12 09:09 conf
drwxr-xr-x 5 root daemon 4096 Mar 11 17:20 htdocs

/apps/redmine$ ls -l  
drwxr-xr-x  3 root daemon    4096 Jan  5 11:21 conf
drwxrwxr-x 19 root daemon    4096 Jan 20 12:15 htdocs
```

Can some one explain please? why redmine works while widgets is forbidden?

Comment: You may want to check whether apache has access to the files and folders on disk, if not, you may need grant permission by chown or chmod first.

Comment: but there is another app, which works normally on the same server.. which is http://192.168.10.18:8080/redmine/

Comment: if they have similar settings in conf, i suspect the problem is still in file permissions on disk, check each file permission under the real path on disk.

Comment: Please see Edit above